# Use AMP with Material Design Lite in angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, architecture, material-design, amp-html

I would like to create an e-commerce progressive web app with angular 5. How can I use AMP with angular 5 in Google Material Design Lite? 
If it is not scalable or feasible then what are the other good options?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I presume that you are already familiar with SSR/server-side rendering using Angular Universal, before anything else. Since **no** custom JavaScript is allowed on AMP.

Having said that, let's talk a bit about AMP standards and restrictions and see what possible issues are when it comes to Angular.

> **1.** How does a website/app implement AMP, in my experience?

Well, you'd practically have 2 versions for each page (the regular version and the AMP version - with strict rules to adhere to).
Let's say you have a video page on `my-app.com/video/1234/some-video-slug`. And you want to tell Google that you have an AMP version for this page. You do that by adding the following in the `<head>`: `<link rel="amphtml" href="my-app.com/video-amp/1234/some-video-slug">` where `/video-amp` would be the route that serves the AMP version. All the next points are about what happens on that AMP route/page.

> **2.** You are **not allowed** to have any external styles

So, no `<link rel="stylesheet" href="path-to-some.css">`.

Only a few allowed by AMP (like Font Awesome `//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/` or Material Icons/Google Fonts `//font.googleapis.com`, so from specific cdns only, definitely NOT hosted on your own server).

**What does this mean?** Well, when on an AMP route, you need to strip the server-rendered document of all external css references that aren't allowed by AMP and add those that are allowed, if/when needed - like when you need some icons or google fonts. Removing and Adding tags in the document (so, this includes the `<head>` section) is possible using the `document` and `renderer` provided by Angular. But, to me it seemed slow even to only traverse the children nodes of the `<head>` section in order to remove any `<link>` tag. And I don't think you could do that outside of your Angular app, since you have very little knowledge about what needs to be done on what route.

> **3.** How do you style your app then?

Well the only custom css that AMP allows you to have is inside a `<style>` block within the document.

**How do you do that?** Well, I don't see any other solution other than having a separate build just for some css, which targets the AMP version and has nothing to do with any Angular/Angular CLI workflow, other than maybe compiling/merging the existing css files you already wrote for your components. And **somehow**, put the generated result in a `<style>` block inside the `<head>` section, only when on the AMP version.

**But** keep in mind that those styles aren't necessarily 100% valid css. You might have `/deep/` or `:host`.

> **4.** You are **not allowed** to have ANY custom JavaScript.

So, basically your entire Angular app code should not be included. You have to strip the server-rendered html out of any `<script>` tags.

> **5.** How do you *javascript* then, without custom JavaScript?

For example, it would seem crazy to not have a sliding menu or a dropdown menu, on mobile. Well... You can! But only by using AMP "components".

You'd have to use `<amp-sidebar>` instead of `<mat-sidenav>` or whatever custom component you might have built. But - somehow - only when on the AMP route, because I love Angular Material components.

**And how does it work? The `<amp-sidebar>`?**

Well, when AMP offers you components, that includes JavaScript. In order to make the sidebar work, you can include: `https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-sidebar-0.1.js`. That is allowed. You generally have a lot of common used/needed components available: `amp-carousel`, `amp-img` (yes, you are **not allowed to simply use** the `<img>` tag), `amp-video`, `amp-accordion`...

> **6.** What about the rest of the HTML document?

Well, by simply passing a server-rendered html of an Angular app through the AMP validator, there are a lot of problems here also:

1. **It errors on any custom attributes.** And Angular is full of those, especially to emulate a native ViewEncapsulation (you've seen all the `_ngcontent-c1` and such attributes). In order to get rid of those, I guess you'd either have to go with `ViewEncapsulation.None`, but then each component style will become global OR strip the server rendered html out of all those `_ng...` attributes and go though a great deal of pain to somehow build an AMP css that only targets by class/id etc. and use more classes in your components to style by anyway.
2. **It also errors on all custom tags** (that aren't AMP, of course).
   And you know Angular apps and Material Components are build with
   those. Even the very first one: `<app-root>`. And, honestly, I
   wouldn't work with anything else other than tag selectors and, in
   some cases attribute selectors (like with Directives).

---

This is all that I could think of, so far.

I would say that implementing AMP on an Angular app is close to impossible at this point in time.

But, given that AMP and Angular are both Google projects, I would expect to see some progress in regards to Angular+AMP soon enough. I've heard someone saying that Rob Wormald actually mentioned something about AMP early this year, like in April at Ng-Conf... But I couldn't find anything on that, or any progress so far, and we're close to 2018 already. Plus, maybe there were just some ideas, not even a road map... don't know!?

Hopefully, with Angular 6! I'm an optimist.

For now, I think that a progressive web-app should be fast enough that AMP wouldn't be able to improve much on that speed (as long as you're not on a bad connection on the first load). I don't know how you'd rank on that, though (having a really good PWA versus implementing AMP - when it's one or the other, not both)

Comment: Thanks @MrCroft ... Your detailed explanation really helps me to decide technical stack.

Comment: @godblessstrawberry I've also reached out to AngularAir channel on YouTube ( https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCdCOpvRk1lsBk26ePGDPLpQ ) they said they'll look into AMP with Angular and plan an episode on that. It's been a month or two since then, but I'm hoping it will happen eventually. I'm just not sure it's possible without waaay too much trouble :)